# unable locate package gawk of ns2 program on linux ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, awk, gawk, ns2

i run the program related to awk ,i get  error:*

```
program 'gawk' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install gawk
You will have to enable the component called 'main'
```

and when i write sudo apt-get install gawk command, i get this

```
[sudo] password for sh: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gawk
```

how can i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

```
You will have to enable the component called 'main'
```

Same, you will need to enable main repository. Just run the below commands to enable `main` repository.

```
sudo add-apt-repository main
sudo apt-get update
```

Now install `gawk` package.